# WPF Browser Control Context menu commands disable

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control, mshtml

Is there any way to remove or disable only one particular command say"View Page Source" when the page is displayed in the Web forms Webbrowser control. Most of the sources I find is disabling the complete right click context menu. But I would just required to only disable one command in context menu. Not the whole Menu.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3219/Component-Based-Development-with-Visual-C or this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2491/Using-MSHTML-Advanced-Hosting-Interfaces could help you.

Answer (score 0):

The below link was useful in understand the concept.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4758/How-to-customize-the-context-menus-of-a-WebBrowser#A1